# Ways to climb up $9$ stairs taking $1, 2$, or $3$ steps at a time

Tags: combinatorics

When I run up a staircase, my stride can carry me up $1$, $2$, or $3$ steps at a time. In how many ways can I run up a $9$-step staircase (given that my last stride lands me on the $9^{\text{th}}$ step)?

I can't do constructive and that's all I know.

Comment: I think this might get you started: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/789804/how-many-distinct-ways-to-climb-stairs-in-1-or-2-steps-at-a-time?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Do you count $3+1+2+3$ and $1+3+3+2$ as different ways for climbing the stairs?

Comment: Hint:  try to set up a recursion.  Let $S_n$ be the number of ways to reach step $n$ and note that if you made it to step $n$ the next to last step must have been one of $n-1, n-2, n-3$.

Comment: I'm going to call it a duplicate of this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868024/number-of-ways-of-walking-up-stairs-and-recurrence-relation?rq=1. The difference between $6$ and $9$ is very marginal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $W_n$ the number of ways for climbing a stair with length $n$ with steps having size $\in\{1,2,3\}$.
We clearly have
$$ W_1 = 1,\qquad W_2= 2,\qquad W_3=4 $$
and since the last step may only be $+1,+2$ or $+3$, for any $n\geq 4$ we have:
$$ W_{n} = W_{n-1}+W_{n-2}+W_{n-3}.$$
Now see [tribonacci numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html). We have $W_9=\color{red}{149}$.

Comment: I got $\color{#f00}{12}$:
$$\texttt{
{0, 0, 3}, {0, 3, 1}, {1, 1, 2}, {1, 4, 0}, {2, 2, 1}, {3, 0, 2}, 
{3, 3, 0}, {4, 1, 1}},
\texttt{{5, 2, 0}, {6, 0, 1}, {7, 1, 0}, {9, 0, 0}
}$$
$\color{#f00}{\texttt{Why ?}}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin: I do not get it: what $\{6,0,1\}$ represents among the ways for writing $9$ as a sum of ones, twos and threes?

Comment: Here $1+1+1+1+1+1+3$ and $1+1+3+1+1+1+1$ count as two different ways.

Comment: +1. Thanks. I got it.  Your proof is quite straightforward.